# Find all Columns and its count of occurrence which have value 1 in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ID     Name     Dept    Project     Job     Platform
A101    1        0        1          1        0
A103    0        1        1          0        1
B201    1        1        0          0        0
C301    1        0        1          1        1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

EDIT: I have tried these queries:

```
SELECT count(sittingreading),count(WatchingTV) FROM table_name WHERE sittingreading IS NOT NULL 

Select COUNT(*) from table_name where column_value=0
```

Comment: SELECT count(sittingreading),count(WatchingTV),....
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE sittingreading IS NOT NULL (Select COUNT(*) from  table_name where column_value=0)

Comment: Please consider adding the code, what have you tried yet

Comment: No, edit your question and put the code in there (properly formatted). http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I am not able to figure it out how can i give the column_values

Comment: I have a scenario where I have to get count of all columns where the column value is 0

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Please show your desired output for the sample data given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case statement in `count()` to make SQL Server only count the rows where you have the value you are looking for.

```
select count(case when T.Name = 0 then 1 end) as NameCount,
       count(case when T.Dept = 0 then 1 end) as DeptCount,
       count(case when T.Project = 0 then 1 end) as ProjectCount
from YourTable as T
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Mikael that solved my issue

Comment: @NishanthSuraj others will find it helpful if you accept this answer.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work